# javascript not working with runat

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runat

I am going to get the value from the HTML TextArea , it is working perfectly until i put runat="server" on the control.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
        if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
            limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
        } else {
            limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
        }
    }
</script>
```

then this is the Body

```
 <div runat="server">
    <%-- Note:Set runnat="server" --%>

    <textarea runat="server" name="limitedtextarea" id="Area" onkeydown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);"
        onkeyup="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);" >
```

i am trying to put the value (of textArea) into a variable, then show it on a label

i really appreciate your help..thanks..

Comment: does limitRext fire (put an alert() in it)

Comment: the error is the javascript wont work with 'runat' ..

what is limit Rext fire? i dont use something like that, perhaps..

Answer (score 1):

When you make any control server side control by using `runat=server` then the ID of that contol get changed,
now you can get the server side control ID in Javascript by using ClientID like

```
document.getElementById('<%=Area.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: Sorry My Utkarsh, can you provide example how to implement this within my code.. where should i put the " document.getElementById('<%=Area.ClientID%>') " .. thanks really..

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `runat="server"` it will change the name of the form elements within, and you're relying on the form having named elements:

```
this.form.limitedtextarea
```

For the textfield, you should be fine to pass just `this`, for the `countdown` you could use an id:

```
onkeydown="limitText(this,document.getElementById('countdowntimer'),100);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send the control reference using `this` keyword and in javascript function use that reference with value to check the limit.By this you can use the same function with may other controls.

```
<textarea runat="server" name="limitedtextarea" id="Area" 
    onkeydown="limitText(this,this.form.countdown,100);"         
    onkeyup="limitText(this,this.form.countdown,100);" >

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >     
       function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) 
       {         

          if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) 
          {             
            limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);         
          } 
          else 
          {             
            limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;         
          }     

      } 
    </script>
```